# is there a way to find the hostname of a vm within the vm?

Tags: virtual-machine

I am using EL5. From the host machine virsh list works to list the vms running on that machine, but how to know the vice-versa ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

That all depends on what OS the VM is. If the VM is linux, then, inside the VM, you can type `hostname` in the command line to get the hostname. In windows, start > run > "sysdm.cpl" will tell you the computer name via GUI. So there's really no way to give one-size-fits-all answer since each OS does it differently.